# Question regarding the similarity of an invertible matrix with its inverse .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the set $S$ of all possible $n×n$ invertible matrices $M$ such that $M$ is similar to $M^{-1}$ .

**My approach**

Actually, I was thinking about this problem when I came across a theorem stating that $\mathbf {every}$ square matrix is $\mathbf {similar}$ to its $\mathbf {transpose} .$

Obviously, for the trivial cases if $M = M^{-1}$ or $M^{-1} = M^t$ , then $S$ consists of all possible orthogonal matrices and matrices of order $2$ over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ as similarity over one holds $\mathbf {iff}$ over another .

Also, I thought that if $M \in S$, then if all  possible eigenvalues of $M$ are $\{ \lambda_j : 1 \leq j \leq k\}$ where each $\lambda_j$ appears $n_j$ times , then all  possible eigenvalues of $M^{-1}$ are $\{ 1/\lambda_j : 1 \leq j \leq k\}$ .

Also, if $TMT^{-1} = M^{-1}$, then $M$ and $T^2$ commutes .

Comment: @Kumar one characterization is that $M$ is such a matrix iff $(M-\lambda I)^k $ has the same rank as $(\lambda M - I)^k$ for all complex $\lambda$ and integers $k$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Sir, can you please explain me how you telling that rank of  $(M-\lambda I)^k$ is same with that of  $(\lambda M-I)^k .$

Comment: I don't think this question has a better answer than "the matrices that are similar to their inverses". Sure, you can say "for each eigenvalue $\lambda$, the Jordan structure for $\lambda$ is equal to that for $\lambda^{-1}$", but that's just restating the question. Note that the set of these matrices is not closed in the Zariski topology (nor in the usual metric topology), so there won't be any answer in terms of identities.

Comment: @darij grinberg,Sir, can you please explain me a little bit about the closedness of $S$ in the Zariski topology, and what do you mean by "there won't be any answer in terms of identities" ???

Comment: @RabiKumarChakraborty: I mean, there won't be a condition like $S=S^T$ (symmetry) or $S^TS = 1$ (orthogonality) or $\det S = 1$. Essentially: No condition that says that some polynomials in the entries of $S$ have to be equal.

Comment: Also $M$ is such a matrix iff it is similar to a "diagonal sum" diag$[A, B, B^{-1}]$ where $A$ has only $\pm 1$ for Eigenvalues and $B$ has Eigenvalues not equal to $0$ or $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer the question for $\mathbf C$. Consider the Jordan canonical form (JCF) $\mbox{bl.diag.}(\lambda_jI_j+N_j,j=1,...r)$ of $M$, where bl.diag. means "block diagonal matrix of...", $I_j$ is the identity matrix of size $n_j$, $N_j$ the matrix of size $n_j$ consisting of zeros except on the first
superdiagonal and where $\lambda_j\neq0$ are the eigenvalues of $M$. They are not necessarily distinct in this way to write the JCF.
The JCF of $M^{-1}$ is then $\mbox{bl.diag.}(\lambda_j^{-1}I_j+N_j,j=1,...r)$.
$M$ and $M^{-1}$ are similar if and only if their JCFs agree except for a permutation of the diagonal blocks. 
Therefore the set of all invertible matrices similar to its inverse consists of all matrices having a JCF $\mbox{bl.diag.}(\lambda_jI_j+N_j,j=1,...r)$ such that $\mbox{bl.diag.}(\lambda_j^{-1}I_j+N_j,j=1,...r)$ is equal to $\mbox{bl.diag.}(\lambda_jI_j+N_j,j=1,...r)$ except for a permutation.
In particular, the set $E$ of its eigenvalues must be stable by the mapping $x\mapsto1/x$, but this is not enough.

The answer for $\mathbf R$ is the same. In this case only the JCF of $M$ has an additional property: $\mbox{bl.diag.}(\overline{\lambda_j}I_j+N_j,j=1,...r)$ is equal to $\mbox{bl.diag.}(\lambda_jI_j+N_j,j=1,...r)$ except for a permutation of the diagonal blocks, where $\overline a$ means the complex conjugate of $a$.